# My commands in spigot plugin doesn't work

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

My spigot plugin doesn't work. On the console, it says the plugin is enabled but i can't run the command in the plugin. Pls help.

This is the main code Plugin.java

```
package lol.quacnooblol.mypvpplugin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Plugin extends JavaPlugin{

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled");
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Plugin Disabled");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

    if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage("You ran this command on the console");
    }

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
        player.sendMessage("You ran the test command in game.");
        return true;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

This is the plugin.yml

```
name: Plugin
version: 0.1
main: lol.quacnooblol.mypvpplugin.Plugin
author: QuacNoobLoL
description: A pvp plugin

command:
  test:
  usage: /<command>
  description: A test command
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the plugin.yml `command` to `commands`

In the future please refer to the [plugin.yml documentation](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_YAML) and remember even a single letter can break your code!

Answer (score 0):

in your Plugin.yml you need to use three spaces and not tab

here is the fixed file:

```yaml
name: Plugin
version: 0.1
main: lol.quacnooblol.mypvpplugin.Plugin
author: QuacNoobLoL
description: A pvp plugin
commands:
   test:
   usage: /<command>
   description: A test command
```

And your Plugin.java onCommand boolean needs the @Override annotation like this:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
   if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test")){
      if(!(sender instanceof Player)){
        sender.sendMessage("You ran this command on the console");
      }
      Player player = (Player)sender;
      if(sender instanceof Player){
         player.sendMessage("You ran the test command in game.");
      }
      return true;
   }   
}
```

this should work